# Were Jon Snow and Arya working together in the episode "The Long Night"?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

I have been reading a lot about *Game of Thrones* S8E3 and what each scene signified. And there is this weird theory that what Jon Snow was doing right before

> Arya stabs the Night King

was on purpose. He was trying to distract the dragon so that

> Arya could have a shot at killing the Night King.

But the scene where is stands in front of the dead dragon and shouts an approximate "Go, go, go" and cuts immediately to the next scene where

> Arya jumps onto the Night King, stabbing him.

**Is there any proof/interview/statement/image from the episode to show that Jon actually was distracting the dragon for next scene to happen?** Or this is this a far-fetched theory?

Comment: I think this is wrong because [Y] was being [Y] when [Y] did [Y]. Otherwise they would have both [Y].

Comment: But  Y ???  I was hoping Jon was being Jon and X was being X with no strategy, no mind connecting - warging. I dont want the moment to be taken away from X, but X and Y working in tandem is great, if the showrunners have given out such info

Comment: The incident X was already preplanned in the season X episode Y. X tells Y that something X will happen. But X realizes Y and rushes towards X2. So, Y knows this already that X would do X3 to Y.

Comment: @NogShine LOL funny i actually understood you.

Comment: WAIT WHAT, to incite incident X was planned - but i thought Y executing the plan X was not planned !! Was this planned by them ?? Z giving the knife to Y, Z egging A to go all out on the NK (you're a good man) thereby feigning a vulnerability(of no one to protect him), and then Y snooping in in the last moment and carrying out X ?? I mean Z can see the future and all - did he see Y doing this to the NK ? It all played out well thats it right ?

Comment: @Anu7 Did Jon actually shout go go go? I thought he was just trying to shout it to death

Comment: i've rewatched that scene so many times and i think my wishful thinking(or the lack of it) makes me think its "go -go-go". To be honest i just thought he was screaming at the dragon @EpicKip

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I know that people have been saying this, [on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones/comments/birt01/spoilers_jon_screamed/), and on this [article from EliteDaily too](https://www.elitedaily.com/p/did-jon-snow-help-arya-kill-the-night-king-this-game-of-thrones-theory-makes-total-sense-17234331).

You can [listen for yourself](https://youtu.be/3F-HMyNRYAA?t=77).  Or play the episode and the moment begins at the 1:16:45 timestamp.

Subtitles show

> Jon Snow's yell as only `[YELLS]`.

In other examples of people yelling real words, they caption the words and I've yet to see foreign subtitles with different content.

[image]

For my opinion, people are reading too much into this scene.  There is no clear evidence and as of yet, no commentary from the directors or the actors backing up this theory.  I love tin foil theories as much as anyone

> (R.I.P The Night King goes to King Landing theory of 2019, you were too beautiful for this world)

but sometimes we have to accept that it's just a theory.

Until conclusive proof comes up otherwise (and I'm doubting it will, the producers in the after the show segment made no mention of this plan, and they have always mentioned such things in the past) I think we should assume it was just a powerful scene.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they would have been more overt if there was a connection here.  Viewers need to realize that the visual medium has severe time restrictions, and dramatic effect typically overrides explaining every detail.  *(imo, the producers were meaning to convey that Theon's self-sacrifice was what bought Arya the time--Theon had been fully redeemed when he met his death which is as big of a deal as Brienne's knighthood.)*

Comment: Thank You ! I'm content ! Arya's moment hasn't been stolen _/\\_

Comment: I really doubt that there could be any connection between Jons and Aryas actions. Neither of both even knew where the other one was or what each other was up to. Jon had the goal to reach the NK when the dragon blocked his way. Arya was running through the castle all the time while Jon was on the open field